# regexp replacement with increment

Tags: bash, perl

Using simple linux script (bash, perl, awk), from that text :

```
## Step
### Action :  
 * press 

## Step 10

## Step 1
```

I want to replace all occurences of `^##[ ]+Step[ ]*[0-9]*$` with `## Step $i`
with i the number of substitutions already done + 1

```
## Step 1
### Action :  
 * press 

## Step 2

## Step 3
```

In fact, I just need it to automatically add numbered heading to my markdown docs!

Comment: Are you writing this file with another script? you can increment a variable with `((variable++))`

Comment: Sure, but this file is handwritten!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Perl solution, you have most of what the regex would look like in your question.

```
s/^##[ ]+Step[ ]*[0-9]*$/"## Step ".(++$i)/e;
```

The /e modifier turns the replacement into an expression which is evaluated, so each time it matches, it'll increment `$i`.

To use this you can pipe your text through this command

```
perl -pe 's/^##[ ]+Step[ ]*[0-9]*$/"## Step ".(++$count)/e;'
```

The -p flag adds a `while` loop around the code executed

Answer (score 1):

A perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe'BEGIN{$i=1} s/^##[ ]+Step[ ]*[0-9]*$/## Step $i/ and $i++;'
```